# How set UnityContainer.Resolve<IType>() types precedence?

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

How to set precedence in `UnityContainer`? for instance, how to tell `Unity` that I want to resolve `IVehicle` to a `Bus`, not a `Car` in the following example?

```
var parent = new UnityContainer();
parent.RegisterType<IVehicle, Car>();
/*
...
*/
var child = parent.CreateChildContainer();

child.RegisterType<IVehicle, Bus>();

// now I want to get Bus, not Car:
var hopefullyBus = child.Resolve<IVehicle>();
```

Comment: IIRC this example should work correctly, have you tried it?

Comment: @Lukazoid, my bad... :-( it works correctly... post an answer so I could accept it

Comment: I have done that now, along with a few other options available to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your example is currently, it should work, this is because you are adding a type registration to a child container which you are then using to perform the resolution of the instance, this results in a `Bus`.

If however you wished to use a single `UnityContainer` instance, you have two options:

One is to add a new type mapping of `<IVehicle, Bus>` to parent and perform the resolve after this, this will overwrite the earlier `<IVehicle, Car>` type mapping.

The other option is to use named registrations and resolve using one of those named registrations, i.e.

```
parent.RegisterType<IVehicle, Car>("car");
parent.RegisterType<IVehicle, Bus>("bus");

// Notice the strings being used match the registrations
var bus = parent.Resolve<IVehicle>("bus"); 
var car = parent.Resolve<IVehicle>("car");
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the name-strings.